# Lost my EFI settings

Tags: 12.04, mac, uefi

So, I installed Ubuntu some weeks ago on my iMac, and I was able to boot directly to it, but I ejected a CD while booting, and now I need to load Ubuntu manually. I tried to use Boot Manager at OS X, but it doesn't detects the system partition. What should I do?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how you were booting before, so it's unclear how you'd restore whatever your previous configuration was. I'll therefore suggest that you install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) or its successor [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). These are boot managers that scan the disk for EFI and BIOS boot loaders and enable you to boot anything that they find. Chances are either one will pick up your "lost" Ubuntu boot loader. Be aware that if you use rEFInd, it defaults to scanning only for EFI boot loaders, so if you had been booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode, you may need to reconfigure rEFInd to scan for BIOS boot loaders by editing the "scanfor" option in its refind.conf configuration file.

Comment: Oh, I installed rEFIt (which, I don't know why, works with Lion), but thanks! :)